# Code Challenge - Visit Maximum Nodes in limited amount of time

Tags: java, optimization, graph-algorithm

Consider this sample timing matrix: (nxn)

```
{
{0, 2, 2, 2, -1}, 
{9, 0, 2, 2, -1}, 
{9, 3, 0, 2, -1}, 
{9, 3, 2, 0, -1}, 
{9, 3, 2, 2,  0}
}
```

Rows 0 and n are the start and end positions respectively.

- I need to always start and end with start node and end node
  respectively.
- I can revisit nodes as sometimes revisiting nodes can add time to the
  clock (negative times possible)
- There can be a case when looping between nodes just keeps adding time to the clock. In that case I can visit all other nodes as I can basically generate time.

Please consider the following table below for a solution for the above particular case:

```
Start End Delta Time
    -   0     -    1 
    0   4    -1    2
    4   2     2    0
    2   4    -1    1
    4   3     2   -1 
    3   4    -1    0
```

After this there is no particular node I can visit therefore the solution is `2, 3` (as 0 and 4 are start and end and have to be visited)

I'm not able to figure an optimal non-brute force algorithm for this.

```
Input: int[][] Timing Matrix, int Time
Output: int[] Visitable Nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

> an optimal non-brute force

Between optimal and brute-force, there are many possibilities. I have no clue, how an optimal solution could look like, but I can present an improvement over brute-force.

Bruteforcing means trying all possible paths. The number of such paths depends on the distances and things get more complicated by the fact that node revisiting is allowed. Ignoring these complication we could naively say that there are `n!` paths to be tried.

A trivial observation is that the two partial paths

```
start -> a -> b -> c
```

and

```
start -> b -> a -> c
```

differ only in the final time available. So for every set of visited nodes (here: `{a, b, c}`) and the final node (here: `c`), you only need to keep track of the minimum time needed. This reduces the naive complexity estimation to `2**n * n`, which is still bad but much better.

---

Concerning the implementation, I'd define

```
class State {
    final ImmutableSet<Node> visitedNodes;
    final Node finalNode;
    ...
}

Map<State, Integer> bestTimeMap;
```

and use it to stop recursion if a state gets re-visited when a previous visit had the same or better time.